# Get all links for my laravel website for sitemap

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, sitemap

I generate sitemap but im getting error when im run composer update in my server.
this package cause an error https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap

because the php version of the server is 7.0 but the requirements for package is 7.1.

their have any alternative solution for this, without updating php version?
or their have a way short way to get all the links of my website? thanks in advance :)

Comment: If the project minimum requirement is php 7.1 there isn't so much you can do with that project; at least you can try forking it...

Comment: spatie laravel 3.3 does not require 7.1

Comment: Problem 1
    - doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.18) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: @Kenneth you can also try this https://github.com/prolificrohit/sitemaps

Answer (score 2):

you can use this package instead:

https://github.com/Laravelium/laravel-sitemap

**here one sample for big sitemap:**

```
/** @var Sitemap $sitemap */
        $sitemap = \App::make("sitemap");


        // add item to the sitemap (url, date, priority, freq)
        $sitemap->add(route('home'), new Carbon(), '1.0', 'hourly');


        $sitemapNumber = 1;
        /** @var Application $application */
        Application::with('applicationImages')->chunk(200, function ($applications) use ($sitemap, &$sitemapNumber) {
            foreach ($applications as $application) {

                $images = [];
                $images[] = ['url' => url($application->icon->url()), 'title' => $application->name];
                if (!empty($application->applicationImages))
                    foreach ($application->applicationImages as $applicationImage) {
                        $images[] = ['url' => url($applicationImage->image->url()), 'title' => $application->name];
                    }

                $sitemap->add(route('application.show', $application->routeArray()), $application->updated_at->format('c'), '0.5', 'daily', $images);

            }
            // generate new sitemap file
            $sitemap->store('xml', 'sitemap-' . $sitemapNumber);
            // add the file to the sitemaps array
            $sitemap->addSitemap(secure_url('sitemap-' . $sitemapNumber . '.xml'));
            // reset items array (clear memory)
            $sitemap->model->resetItems();
            // count generated sitemap
            $sitemapNumber++;
        });

        $sitemap->store('sitemapindex', 'sitemap', public_path());
        return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a long winded way around but this worked for me. I created an array of the urls and respective loc, lastmod, change etc.  I wrote a function to render the XML into a string

```
function renderXML($array) {
        $response = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';
      foreach ($array as $item) {
        $response .= '<url>
              <loc>' .  url('/') . '/' . $item['uri']  . '</loc>' .
              '<lastmod>'. $item['publishes_at'] . '</lastmod>' .
              '<changefreq>'. $item['changefreq'] .'</changefreq>' .
              '<priority>' .$item['priority'] . '</priority>' .
          '</url>';
      }

        $response .='</urlset>';
        return $response;
}
```

Then called it from controller

```
return response(self::renderXML($array))->withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'text/xml']);
```

This is supposing your links are stored in a database or generated dynamically like blogs etc. This also worked for the sitemapindex but different structure. Our site is only quite small with 6000 links. I'd be interested to know of a better way of doing it without using tp.